# applying css ribbon on bootstrap 3 Jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap 3 Jumbotron where I am trying to apply a ribbon on the corner. Now grant it there are tons of samples of how to apply a css ribbon online, but not on a bootstrap 3 Jumbotron. I believe the classes are conflicting with the ribbon classes and I can not figure out why It just won't sit on the Jumbotron. see below

```css
.ribbon-wrapper-green {
width: 180px;
height: 172px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: -4px;
right: -4px;
}

.ribbon-green {
  font: bold 12px Sans-Serif;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0px 1px 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:      rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  padding: 7px 0;
  left: -5px;
  top: 45px;
  width: 235px;
  background-color: #BFDC7A;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#BFDC7A), to(#8EBF45)); 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  color: #6a6340;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.ribbon-green:before, .ribbon-green:after {
  content: "";
  border-top:   3px solid #6e8900;   
  border-left:  3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green:before {
  left: 0;
}
.ribbon-green:after {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="ribbon-wrapper-green"><div class="ribbon-green">The Flagship Programme of<br />Aaaaa Aaaaaa Aaaaaaaaa</div></div>
  <div class="jumbotron">
  
    <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>      
    <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
  </div>
  <p>This is some text.</p>      
  <p>This is another text.</p>      
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add position relative for jumbotron class and move ribbon inside jumbotron.

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:20px;">

  <div class="jumbotron" class="relative">
    <div class="ribbon-wrapper-green"><div class="ribbon-green">The Flagship Programme of<br />Aaaaa Aaaaaa Aaaaaaaaa</div></div>
    <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>      
    <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
  </div>
  <p>This is some text.</p>      
  <p>This is another text.</p>      
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    .ribbon-wrapper-green {
width: 180px;
height: 172px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: -4px;
right: -4px;
}

.ribbon-green {
  font: bold 12px Sans-Serif;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0px 1px 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:      rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  padding: 7px 0;
  left: -5px;
  top: 45px;
  width: 235px;
  background-color: #BFDC7A;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#BFDC7A), to(#8EBF45)); 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  color: #6a6340;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.ribbon-green:before, .ribbon-green:after {
  content: "";
  border-top:   3px solid #6e8900;   
  border-left:  3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
}
.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
}

.ribbon-green:before {
  left: 0;
}
.ribbon-green:after {
  right: 0;
}
```

You will get ribbon on jumbotron.

Comment: it is now on the Jumbotron, but too far down. how can I scoot it up without breaking